# Cross-layer filtering extension with more then 2 filter query is not working

Tags: cql, geoserver

i have a Query like below

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=json&request=getfeature&typename=tiger:poly_landmarks,tiger:poi&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('tiger:poly_landmarks', 'the_geom','LAND=83','CFCC=H11'))
```

Which gives 3 features

```
    {
"type": "FeatureCollection"
"totalFeatures": 3
"features": [3]
0:  {
"type": "Feature"
"id": "poly_landmarks.3"
...More
```

But if i add one more filter to the querySingle **'LANAME=East River'** as below

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=json&request=getfeature&typename=tiger:poly_landmarks,tiger:poi&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('tiger:poly_landmarks', 'the_geom','LAND=83','CFCC=H11','LANAME=East River'))
```

Gives error saying

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>Could not parse CQL filter list. Function not found. Parsing : INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('tiger:poly_landmarks', 'the_geom','LAND=83','CFCC=H11','LANAME=East River')).</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html) it seems that querySingle only takes 3 arguments so your way won't work. I suspect (i.e. I haven't tested this in this context) you can construct a more complex [CQL filter](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html) by using `AND`. So I would try

```
 querySingle('tiger:poly_landmarks', 'the_geom','LAND=83 AND CFCC=H11 AND LANAME=East River'))
```

Comment: Thanks @iant its working i made it like this `code`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs/?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&outputFormat=json&request=getfeature&typename=tiger:poly_landmarks,tiger:poi&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom, querySingle('tiger:poly_landmarks', 'the_geom','LAND=''83'' AND CFCC=''H11'' AND LANAME=''East River'''))`code`